# How to create instantaneous HTML form when onclick clicked

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have a list of html images with onclick event added.

```
`<img src="<?php echo $name ?>" alt="<?php echo $name ?>" onclick="somefunc()">`
```

I want to create and instantaneous HTML form  as soon as the user clicks on one of the images with form value=image id  and auto submit that form.

how can I achieve that?

I tried putting html form inside a javascript function thinking that the form is only created once the function is called by the onclick event but the form is created even when the function is not called.
The function is something like

```
  <script>
 function somefun(){
  </script>
   <form id="myform" method="get" action="index.php">
   <input type="hidden" name="sel" value="6">
  <script> 
  document.getElementById('myform').submit();
 }
 </script>
```

and auto submit not working when the image is clicked.I have been battling for two days any help will be deeply appreciated.

Hey thanks everyone for trying to help me,
I tried your way but soon ran into errors so decided to take entirely different approach.In my next approach i used java script to create a cookie when the img is clicked and redirect to another page and use that cookie when loading next page.Code is something like below.

```
<img src="something.png" onclick="fun(<?php echo $value; ?>)">
<script>
     function fun(mid){
     var="index.php"
     document.cookie = "myid="+mid;
     window.open(uri);
     }
</script>
```

and in the index.php i used that cookie value.The code is something like below

```
<?php
$mid=$_COOKIE['myid'];//got the value
?>
```

Comment: I tried putting HTML form inside a java script function thinking that the form will only be created once the function is called by onclick event trigger but the html form is created even when the function is not called.

Comment: hey everyone thanks for tring to help me

Answer (score 0):

I do not know PHP but this should work as in Javascript.

1. call the function with onclick
2. extend the dom with Javascript or in your case with PHP
3. post the form

Example for DOM Manipulation with Javascript

```
function somefunction(){
    var imageUrl = 'urlToImg'
    var htmlElement = $("#htmlElement");
    var html = '<div><img id="image" class="image-styling" src="' + imageUrl + '"></div>';
    modalBody.append(html);
    postForm();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well for starters when dealing with forms and you want to use an event as to click on an element and submit a form directly.

1. I advise you to use ajax because it will be easier and better in customizing details and when you need to reflect directly on the page without reloading.
2. For the Onclick method i think you should use .On("click" method better for all elements and using a selector as a class name from the js file directly.

   ```
   $("img.imgclicked").on( "click", function(event) {
       var idofelement = event.target.id;
   }
   ```

You can check this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/x8xbzttf/5/

http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

I hope I have answered your Question.